# How can this code be of type pointer to pointer to void?

Tags: c, pointers

I am studying c language now.
While studying, I saw the code, but there is one part I don't understand.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    pthread_t  t_id;
    int arg = 10;
    int result;
    int *p;

    result = pthread_create(&t_id, NULL, thread_main, (void *)&arg);
    if(result != 0){
        errno = result;
        perror("create");
    }
    pthread_join(t_id, (void *)&p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

```
pthread_join(t_id, (void *)&p);
```

If it is forced casting, I think it should be `(void*)type` but
I am wondering how the variable p turns from `(void*)&p` to a `void**p` type.

Shouldn't it be written in `(void**)&p`

Comment: its because  `pthread_join` takes address of a pointer `int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);`

Comment: I know the function form, but I don't know how pointer casting works.

Comment: The code is simply incorrect, as is the `printf` that follows it.

Comment: Changing it to `(void**)&p` is also incorrect. The correct thing to do is to declare `p` as `void *p;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines of code are incorrect:

```
   int *p;
   /* ... */
    pthread_join(t_id, (void *)&p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
```

`pthread_join`'s second parameter is `void **retval` and if non-null, will copy the exit value of the thread to `*retval`. The exit value and the type of `*retval` are both of type `void*` as far as `pthread_join` is concerned, but the underlying object `p` in the caller is of type `int*`. This results in *undefined behavior* because the *effective type* of `p` is its declared type `int *` but its stored value is being accessed by an *lvalue expression* (`*retval`) that does not satisfy the requirements of [C11 6.5/7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:<sup>88)</sup>
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.
>
> ---
>
> 88) The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which an object may or may not be aliased.

The cast operation `(void *)&p` serves to hide the problem. Any value of an object pointer type can be converted to `void *` and back to the original pointer type and will compare equal to the original pointer value. But in this case, the pointer value is being converted back to a different, incompatible pointer type.

The `printf("%d\n", *p);` is not incorrect itself, but the storage location `*p` was accessed incorrectly by the call to `pthread_join`, so the value of `p` and therefore the value of `*p` may be invalid.

Assuming the thread's exit value is actually a `void *` pointing to an `int` object, the code can be written as follows to avoid the undefined behavior:

```
   void *pv;
   int *p;
   /* ... */
   pthread_join(t_id, &pv);
   p = pv;
   printf("%d\n", *p);
```

Or, omitting the extra variable:

```
   void *pv;
   /* ... */
   pthread_join(t_id, &pv);
   printf("%d\n", *(int *)pv);
```